# How do I get find a word that contains some specific letter AND one in particular (using regex)?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Hello everyone and thank you in advance,

I am trying to get a all the words in the following list except for "motiu" and "diomar" using regex and python:

```
amfora
difamador
difamar
dimorf
dofi
fada
far
farao
farda
fiar
fiord
fira
firar
firma
for
motiu
diomar
```

The word must not contain a letter outside the list [diomarf], but it must contain an "f"

I don't know much about regex...I have tried with some, they are getting more complex but I haven't got the solution yet. Some of the expressions I have tried with are:

```
> (?:.*f)(?:.*[diomarf])
> (?:.*[diomarf])(?:.*f)
> (?:((?:f)+)(?:[diomarf])*)
> (?:((?:[diomarf])+)(?:f)*)
> (?:((?:[diomarf])*)((?:f)+))
> (?:(((?:f)+)((?:[diomarf])*)))
> (?:((?:f)+((?:[diomarf])*)))
```

The expression with which I think I got the closest result is:

> (?:(((?:f)+)((?:[diomarf])*)))

But it only checks from the first f of the word, for example, for "dimorf" I am only getting the last "f"

Comment: @depperm All but the last two must match, see "*I am trying to get a all the words in the following list except for "motiu" and "diomar"*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^f[diomarf]*$|^[diomarf]*f[diomarf]*$|^[diomarf]*f$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wq0cly/1)

Explanation:
`^f[diomarf]*$` : A string either starts with f and then has any number of characters from this list [diomarf] (including 0!)
OR
`^[diomarf]*f[diomarf]*$` the string has f somewhere in the middle
OR
`^[diomarf]*f$` f at the end

The previous solution I proposed fails when disallowed characters are added to the end of the string (for example diomarfg).

Old solution for reference:

```
(?=[diomarf]).*f.*
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/sBFyLI/1)

Explanation:

`(?=[diomarf])` - use positive lookahead to assert that at any point in the string one of the allowed letters is matched.

`.*f.*` - make sure that the letter f is somewhere in the string.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Have a happy new year!

Answer (score 2):

You can write the pattern as:

```
^[diomar]*f[diomarf]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[diomar]*` Optionally repeat matching one of the allowed chars excluding the `f`
- `f` Match the mandatory `f`
- `[diomarf]*` Optionally repeat matching one of the allowed chars
- `$` End of string

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/XKRzXr/1).

Comment: Excellent! **For future visitors:** If the whole string is not supposed to be matched i.e. only words are supposed to be matched, it will become`\b[diomarf]*?f[diomarf]*\b`.

Comment: ✨ Going to sleep too :-) Good new year 4th bird already.  